# How to get usernames and userIDs from asp.net-membership and bind it to dropdown listz?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-membership

I'm trying to get userName and userID From `Membership.GetAllUsers()` to bind it to dropdown list

```
   private void Bind_usersList()
    {
        var dictionary = Membership.GetAllUsers().Cast<MembershipUser>();
    }
```

Comment: To the community: I tried Googling this, but what's out there is junk, so a good, canonical answer would be nice here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `MembershipUser` has no "userID" but a `ProviderUserKey` which could be a `Guid`(f.e. in `SqlMembershipProvider`).

This should work:

```
MembershipUserCollection members = Membership.GetAllUsers();
DdlUsers.DataSource = members.Cast<MembershipUser>()
    .ToDictionary(m => m.ProviderUserKey, m =>  m.UserName);
DdlUsers.DataValueField = "Key";
DdlUsers.DataTextField = "Value";
DdlUsers.DataBind();
```

Comment: I wasn't aware of `ToDictionary`'s existence. Learn something new every day.

Comment: @ean5533: Yeah, I stumbled onto `ToDictionary` one day myself.  Tripping over undiscovered things seems to be my learning mode nowadays; being up to speed on everything is hard, unless you're one of these folks who read MSDN cover to cover.